# Minimal DFA for $1\Sigma^*0$

Tags: finite-automata

What is the minimum number of states required in any DFA to accept the regular language $L$ over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ which accepts those strings that start with 1 and end with 0?

Comment: According to me, the answer is 2. But I am not sure, have some doubt, so I am looking for your kind help.

Comment: Can you come up with a DFA having only two states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A} = \langle \Sigma, Q, q_0, \delta, F\rangle$ be a DFA for $L$. Then, note that the $|Q|\geq 4$. Indeed, the states $q_0, \delta(q_0, 0), \delta(q_0, 1)$ have to be distinct, and clearly all of them are rejecting (can you tell why they're rejecting?) and thus as there are words in $L$, we know that there has to be at least one additional accepting state. To see why the later states are distinct, note that we have:

- from $q_0$ you can get to an accepting state, and from $\delta(q_0, 0)$ you cannot get to an accepting state. Hence, $q_0$ and $\delta(q_0, 0)$ are distinct.
- from $\delta(q_0, 1)$ you can get to an accepting state, and from $\delta(q_0, 0)$ you cannot get to an accepting state. Hence, $\delta(q_0, 1)$ and $\delta(q_0, 0)$ are distinct.
- from $\delta(q_0, 0)$ you cannot get to an accepting state, and from $\delta(\delta(q_0, 1), 0)$ you can get to an accepting state. Hence, $q_0$ and $\delta(q_0, 1)$ are distinct.

Now you can actually, build a DFA for L consisting of exactly 4 states. You can start from what we already know: the above three states are rejecting, and the 4'th additional state have to be accepting. So you only need to add the transitions between the 4 states properly.

Answer (score 4):

*The following answer assumes that each state in a DFA must contain an outgoing edge for each symbol. Otherwise, you might need one state fewer.*

Let us say that two words $x,y$ are *equivalent* modulo $L$ if for any word $z$, either both $xz$ and $yz$ are in $L$, or both of them are not in $L$.

If two words $x,y$ are *not* equivalent modulo $L$, and $A$ is any DFA accepting $L$, then the state of $A$ after reading $x$ must be different from the state of $B$ after reading $y$ (why?).

As a consequence, if $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is a collection of words, any two of which are not equivalent modulo $L$, then any DFA for $L$ must contain at least $n$ states.

(Furthermore, it is known that if the minimal DFA for $L$ contains $n$ states, then we can find $n$ such words: for each state, we take some word leading to it; but we don't need this direction here.)

In your case, the following words are pairwise inequivalent: $\epsilon, 0, 1, 10$. To show this, we need to consider all six pairs:

- $\epsilon,0$ are inequivalent since $10 \in L$ but $010 \notin L$.
- $\epsilon,1$ are inequivalent since $0 \notin L$ but $10 \in L$.
- $\epsilon,10$ are inequivalent since $\epsilon \notin L$ but $10 \in L$.
- $0,1$ are inequivalent since $00 \notin L$ but $10 \in L$.
- $0,10$ are inequivalent since $0 \notin L$ but $10 \in L$.
- $1,10$ are inequivalent since $1 \notin L$ but $10 \in L$.

This shows that every DFA for $L$ contains at least $4$ states. Conversely, there is a DFA for $L$ containing $4$ states, which I will let you figure out.

Answer (score -2):

[image]

The minimal DFA is attached.
Here, q0 is the initial state and q2 is the final state.